# jquery hash if no hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

Trying to get #home to display if there is no hash present in the url. I figured something along these lines would work pretty easy but I can't get anything going:

```
   if(window.location.hash != null){ 
      $(window.location.hash).fadeIn(800);
   } else {
      $('#home').fadeIn(800);
   }
```

I've never worked with if / else statements in jquery, so this is obviously wrong

thanks!

Comment: will `window.location.hash` give `null`? Maybe you should check for that first in some `JS API`. I think it will give you an empty string.

Comment: @Marnix, You're correct. At least in Firefox it will give an empty string.

Comment: that's exactly what it was, so i changed to empty and works perfect!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Compare it against the empty string instead (null and the empty string aren't equal in JavaScript):

```
if(window.location.hash != ''){ 
   $(window.location.hash).fadeIn(800);
} else {
   $('#home').fadeIn(800);
}
```